# ¿Como usar una variable de una función fuera de esta?

Tags: python

Mi pregunta es como puedo usar la variable `ganar` y las variables de los `puntos` fuera de la función, he intentado de varias formas pero no me funciona.

```
puntos_j_1, global puntos_j_2 = 0,0
j_1, j_2 = "Papel", "Tijeras"

def Ganar (j_1, j_2):
    global puntos_j_1
    global puntos_j_2
    if j_1 == "piedra":
        if j_2 == "Papel":
            ganar = "Jugador 2"
            puntos_j_2 += 1
        if j_2 == "Tijeras":
                   ganar = "Jugador 1"
                   puntos_j_1 += 1
    if j_1 == "Papel":
        if j_2 == "Tijeras":
            ganar = "Jugador 2"
            puntos_j_2 += 1
        if j_2 == "Piedra":
            ganar = "Jugador 1"
            puntos_j_1 += 1
    if j_1 == "Tijeras":
        if j_2 == "Piedra":
            ganar = "Jugador 2"
            puntos_j_2 += 1
        if j_2 == "Papel":
            ganar = "Jugador 1"
            puntos_j_1 += 1
      
ganar(j_1, j_2)
print (ganar)
```

No se si se debe de usar (pass o return) o si de plano no se deben de usar

Comment: En python, el resultado de una función se devuelve con la sentencia `return`. Asignar un resultado al nombre de la función es cosa de otros lenguajes (¿visual basic, tal vez?).

Comment: Tu código contiene errores de sintaxis. ¿Lo probaste antes de subirlo?

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta se entiende muy poco, a continuación explico todo lo que creo que puedes estar preguntando.

Obtener un valor de una función:

```
def suma():
    c = 2 + 5
    return c

# resultado contiene el valor de la suma
resultado = suma()
```

Obtener y modificar variables con una función:

```
a = 2
b = 5

def suma(valor1, valor2):
    c = valor1 + valor2
    return c

# pasa las variables a la funcion
resultado = suma(a, b)
```

Obtener y modificar variables sin pasarlas a la función:

```
a = 2
b = 5

def suma():
    # accede a las variables fuera de la funcion
    global a, b

    c = a + b
    return c

resultado = suma()
```